# wide to long format from a list of items in the column [ ] in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

input data frame below

```
 data1 = {
'IDs':  ['A1','A10','A11','A12','A13','A14','A17'],
'S_S': ['G001','' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,],
'St_s': ['Pa', '','' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,],
'SsFlag': ['Pr','' ,'' ,'' , '', '', '',],
'id' : [32,10,11,12,11,12,17],
'flag': [[ '68'],[ '68'],['12','34','6'],['24'],['20','21','34'],['14', '20'],['10', '68']]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)
```

Inital output

```
df
Out[131]: 
    IDs   S_S St_s SsFlag  id          flag
0   A1  G001   Pa     Pr  32          [68]
1  A10                    10          [68]
2  A11                    11   [12, 34, 6]
3  A12                    12          [24]
4  A13                    11  [20, 21, 34]
5  A14                    12      [14, 20]
6  A17                    17      [10, 68]
```

Required output

```
IDs   S_S    St_s SsFlag  id          flag
A1   G001   Pa     Pr    32          [68]
A10                      10          [68]
A11                      11          [12]
A11                      11          [34]
A11                      11          [6]
A12                      12          [24]
A13                      11          [20]
A13                      11          [21]
A13                      11          [34]
A14                      12          [14]
A14                      12          [20]
A17                      17          [10]
A17                      17          [68]
```

The the flag column needs to rearrange and other columns gets filled up automatically I am not sure if a pd.wide_to_long or pd.melt or any apply function will do the job

I tried this from the below link as mentioned in the comments, getting the following output,

[How to unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
    s=pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in zip(df.index,df.flag) for z in y])
    ss = s.merge(df,left_on=0,right_index=True)

```
ss
Out[141]: 
    0   1   ID   S_S St_s SsFlag  id          flag
0   0  68   A1  G001   Pa     Pr  32          [68]
1   1  68  A10                    10          [68]
2   2  12  A11                    11   [12, 34, 6]
3   2  34  A11                    11   [12, 34, 6]
4   2   6  A11                    11   [12, 34, 6]
```

Comment: `df.explode('flag')` for `pandas >= 0.25.0`

Comment: print(pd.__version__)
0.24.2

Comment: Still a duplicate, see the accepted answer in link I provided, which showcases many methods to help your problem, without using `explode`.

Comment: Hi Erfan, I updated with the link you have suggested, please provide some info.

Comment: print(pd.__version__) 0.25.0 explode and this example works for 0.25.0

Answer (score 3):

What about `df.explode('flag')` which works in recent versions of pandas.

Comment: Rather flag as duplicate, cause there are extensive answers on this topic.